# Gridview postback datasource persistance

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid that is data bound to a generic list. Which I edit and need to persist the changes of, to the db.

The problem is when I hit the submit button it does a PostBack. And sets the data source of the gridview to null.

I've tried storing the data source in the view state ViewState["data"] which works great but the data isn't being updated in the ViewState when changes are made on the grid.

Any ideas?

Here is the code for the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgMerchantConfiguration" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CausesValidation="False" CustomPagerCssClass="" HeaderHeight="30px" NumberOfPagesHeight="15px"
    NumberOfPagesWidth="40px" PagerHeight="15px" PagerWidth="40px" ShowDataGridCustomPaging="None"
    SortHeight="15px" SortWidth="70px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderWidth="1px"
    CellPadding="1" Font-Size="Smaller" GridLines="Vertical" Width="100%" 
    onrowdatabound="dgMerchantConfiguration_RowDataBound" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="False">
    <SelectedRowStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#f80000"></SelectedRowStyle>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#EEEEEE"></RowStyle>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#bd0000" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
    <FooterStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#CCCCCC"></FooterStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CommissionType" HeaderText="Commission Type">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Selected") %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Override">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOverride" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Default") %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkOverride_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comission Structure">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpCommissionStructure" runat="server" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCommissionStructure_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Min">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMin" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Bind("Min") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Max">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMax" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Bind("Max") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fixed">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFixed" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Bind("Fixed") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost Per Unit">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCostPerUnit" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Bind("CostPerUnit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Value">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitValue" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Bind("UnitValue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Excluded Amount">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExclAmount" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Bind("ExcludedAmount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Percentage">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalBold"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Normal"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPercentage" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%# Bind("Percentage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And how the data source is set:

```
protected void ddlMerchants_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load the selected businesses config from the db
    var t = client.GetMerchantCommissionStructure(new GetMerchantCommissionStructureRequest() { MerchantID = Int32.Parse(ddlMerchants.SelectedItem.Value) });

    ViewState["data"] = t.Configurations;
    dgMerchantConfiguration.DataSource = t.Configurations;
    dgMerchantConfiguration.DataBind();
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataGridView becomes null for some reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067997/datagridview-becomes-null-for-some-reason)

Comment: You can use the `Session` which is much better than `ViewState` since it will be stored in server memory instead of being transmitted always between server and client. But i would use the session only in an intranet apprlication with few users. **Why do you need to persist the datasource at all?** It could be outdated already. The `GridView` stores its content already in the `ViewState`. So if you need to access it on the next postback  use `FindControl` to get the controls. If you made changes you should reload the updated datasource.

Comment: Hi Tim I need to persist the data source because i need to save the changes to the db. Shouldn't the data source be updated each time a change is made on the grid? And then with    FindControl would i need to loop through the gridview and call find control on each row for each cell?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I would avoid using Session for a few reasons: 1) since it is stored in RAM on the web server, then storing potentially large amounts of data like tables can cause memory pressure and scalability issues.  2) if a user opens up two different tabs for the same webpage (or even worse 2 separate pages that both use Session["data"]), then you run into conflicts.  Session is stored per user, and it not tied to any specific instance of a single web page, so you should avoid storing data that is specific to one instance of one page in session.

Comment: @BateTech: it depends, as always. Storing temporarily some megabytes in memory is much more efficient than always transferring it between client and server in the page's viewstate. Even MS Reporting Services(SSRS) is implemented in this way. But of course, it's much better to avoid persisting the datasource but to load it again from db.

Comment: @MattBH: Why do you need to persist it then? The `GridView` maintains it's state already in the `ViewState`. You just have to use the `GridView`'s events like the [`RowUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx) event. But you can even use a custom method and use `FindControl` to get the controls. They will contain the changed text.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree, the use Session does depend on the situation, but in this situation I would strongly recommend against it. Example: User opens data for Merchant 1 in tab 1, and then a new tab opens data for Merchant 2 in tab 2.  If user then switches back to tab 1 and tries to save Merchant 1 data, then the Session["data"] object for that user has been overwritten by Merchant 2 data when tab 2 was loaded and chaos ensues.